# UWP Timeline control

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am writing a UWP app which needs to show milestones against multiple, grouped tasks along a timeline of a video. Basically showing when a task occurred in the timeline. Image below of a crappy excel mock up of what I am talking about.

I have searched and can find some charting option but they are for WPF, javascript or .Net Framework.

Was thinking I could have a go at one myself using a grid as a base and I'm OK on this front for the moment, I am wanting to know if anyone knows of any suitable timeline controls for UWP or can think of another way to visualise this sort of data using available controls.

[image: Example]

Comment: Telerik's grid control is first thing that came to my mind. you can do something similar with that thing. And they recently made their controls for UWP free (for non comercial use at least)

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of options for UWP if you wanting to just xaml output a DataGrid  the only free one I've seen is this

https://github.com/RSuter/MyToolkit

However if your willing to fork some cash there are lots of options. The obvious solution would be which is free for non-commercial use so you can give it a test.

http://www.telerik.com/universal-windows-platform-ui which has a great datagrid

the concept would be removing the first column and adding a new one at the end in a poll

The other option which I thought about mentioning before is https://www.syncfusion.com/ they have a graph library for UWP I have never used there product so I can't really say much about it except I believe they do have a timeline graph.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware they had relicensed their UWP stuff. You're answer is helpful if I have to resort to a Grid but I've just updated my question to clarify.

Comment: Ok I added a bit about a graph solution instead of a data-grid solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old now but I have just had the same issue. After a day of research I have discovered the SyncFusion CellGrid does this perfectly.

https://help.syncfusion.com/uwp/cellgrid/getting-started